# Call web application service from another web application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cross-domain, share

here is the story.
I have two java web applications(app1 and app2). Two apps are based on jsp+springMVC+hibernate and running on different servers BUT share one database.

Now I would like to add one function in app1, which is:
In a page(p1) that is provided from app1, which has a button - "GO APP2". When user clicks this button, he will be redirected to a page(p2) which is provided by app2's servlet, and meanwhile, some data sent from app1 that will also be displayed on p2.

Without using any client side method(cookie, session, cross-domain localStorage), how can i design this function in server side?.... thanks..

Comment: Hm, maybe I do not understand your question, but you can simply pass those parameters as part of the link (form and/or HTTP parameters).

Comment: Hello,do u mean I can do post/get with data and also redirect to that page?

Comment: @user2443316, yes you can. It's basic http.